# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mortbay.thread.Timeout.tick(J)V

Tags: java, maven, jetty

i use jetty in the dubbo.when i start to run the jar,i get info(Cycle output in approximately 0.5 second cycle):

```
2018-03-22 17:08:35.830::INFO:  Stopped SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:9099
2018-03-22 17:08:35.830::WARN:  EXCEPTION
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.mortbay.thread.Timeout.tick(J)V
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:775)
        at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectorManager.doSelect(SelectorManager.java:192)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.nio.SelectChannelConnector.accept(SelectChannelConnector.java:124)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.AbstractConnector$Acceptor.run(AbstractConnector.java:708)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:497)
```

The service can be used normally, but the console always outputs the above information.

part of my pom.xml about jetty:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-util -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.2.v20140723</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-server -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.8.v20171121</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty-threadpool -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-threadpool</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.0pre2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mortbay.jetty/jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

i don`t know why.please help me.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's a "dubbo"?

Comment: a rpc framework that developed by alibaba .you can learn more about dubbo from "dubbo.io".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not mix versions of jetty.

Use same version of jetty across your project's pom.